# batch result me "echo off" instead the proper result

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a little problem with the next code

```
@Echo off
Title STARTING
cls
echo.
echo Checking running services...
echo.
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >NUL
tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v | find /I /N "DATABASESERVER" >NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
cls
echo.
echo Database is not running, now will start!
echo.
start database.bat
echo Database is running! 
echo.
timeout /t 4 /nobreak >NUL
)
tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v | find /i /n "ARMASERVER" >NUL
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" (
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time%") do (
   set /A "ora=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)
echo %ora%
pause
cls
echo.
echo Server is not running, now will start!
echo.
start arma.bat
title EPOCHSERVER
timeout /t 39 /nobreak >NUL
)
```

The problem is that "echo %ora%" it give me the result "Echo off" instead the value of time in seconds

What is the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [enable delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v | find /i /n "ARMASERVER" >NUL
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" (
  for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time%") do (
     set /A "ora=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
  )
  echo percent inside ^(^)=%ora%
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo exclamation=!ora!
  endlocal
)
echo percent  outside ^(^)=%ora%
```

Output:

```
==>D:\bat\SO\30834591.bat
percent inside ()=
exclamation=214860
percent  outside ()=214860

==>
```

Answer (score 1):

`%ora%` is empty at that point, which means that the command being executed is just `echo`, which returns the state of echo.

Are you sure that the quotation marks on the `set` line should be there?

Someone with better batch skills will speak up; I don't want to risk misleading you with my half-educated guesses.

In the meantime, I recommend that you play with that line directly on the commandline until you get the results you expect. Remember to de-double the `%` characters outside of the batch script.